# Problem fitting 2 inputs to my keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm working on a neural network that is supposed to evaluate positions from board games.
The model takes 2 inputs, performs feature extraction using autoencoders on each input separately, and then the output of the autoencoders connects to the rest of the model.

I used the functional API to form the model:

```
input1 = keras.layers.Input(85)
input2 = keras.layers.Input(85)
encoder1 = autoencoder(input1)
encoder2 = autoencoder(input2)
connector = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([encoder1, encoder2])
layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu')(connector)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=layer1)
model.summary()
```

It looks like this:
[image]

But after compiling it, when I try to run:

```
model.fit([x_train1, x_train2], y_train, epochs=3)
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Does anyone know why this error is occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

is this the error?

`inputs=[input1, input2]`

Comment: No sorry, I just accidentally posted the code without that '='. I edited it (the issue is still the same).